# Prestashop: Paypal checkout very slow

Tags: paypal, prestashop

I have a problem with the Paypal integration in the checkout: it is very slow.
It will take approx 20s when I click on the Paypal button (see picture below), before redirecting me to Paypal portal.

[image]

I noticed that the button points to `javascript:$('#paypal_payment_form_payment").submit();`
There will be a lot of POST made to `/checkout-fields?ajax=1` before the site redirects to Paypal. Each call is marked as slow.

Any idea where should I look? I have the "Responsive One Step Checkout / One Page Checkout" module for Prestashop 1.6.1.6.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Open `/modules/paypal/paypal_logos.php` and search for following line and comment it out or delete it.

```
$this->updatePictures($logo[0], $destination);
```